# File Downloads in Internet Explorer over SSL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, http, ssl, download

After recently switching my Rails 3.0 application over to SSL, I've been having issues with file downloads in Internet Explorer. Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome. After extensive searching, I'm fairly confident that the issue is related to the Cache-Control HTTP response header.

So in the code, I'm manually removing both Cache-Control and Pragma right before I call send_file.

```
response.headers.delete("Pragma")
response.headers.delete('Cache-Control')
send_file(response_letter_path, :filename=>"aod_response_letter.docx", :disposition=>'inline')
```

But when I view the HTTP Response using Firebug or the Chrome Dev tools, it still shows "Cache-Control:private".

So first of all, am I on the right track towards solving this IE issue? And second, is this the proper way to remove headers from the HTTP response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're on the right track.

I just ran into this and solved it by adding the following line before the send_file call.
`response.headers.delete('Cache-Control')`

Rails sets the HTTP header Cache-Control: no-cache by default.  Since IE uses the disk cache to playback the video, it throws a 'can't find playback file' error.